# DDE link in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, dde

I am using Visual Studio (C#) program (that's compiled/published), and want to use a DDE link (WinWedge) to monitor the data.  The data flowing into WinWedge will be the data that is read.  The data being read will be connected to a gauge, and the gauge will adjust according to the data.  I know how to do this in VB Excel Macro, but I want to use a more powerful language like C#.  I do not know how to code this, but I am using the open source NDde, and would like help addressing how to code this to connect.  (Source:  http://ndde.codeplex.com/)

Excel VBA Macro:

```
Sub GetSWData()
Dim R As Long
Dim Chan As Long
Dim Feed_1, Feed_1_Units, Feed_2, Feed_2_Units, Dout_1, Dout_1_Units, Dout_2, Dout_2_Units As Variant
Dim vDat As Variant
Dim sDat As String

' Find the next blank row in Column A (Sheet 2)
R = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Chan = DDEInitiate("WinWedge", "Com12") ' Establish DDE link to WinWedge on Com1

Feed_1 = DDERequest(Chan, "Field(3)")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(R, 2).Value = Feed_1(1)
Feed_1_Units = DDERequest(Chan, "Field(4)")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(R, 3).Value = Feed_1_Units(1)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Static").Cells(2, 2).Value = Feed_1(1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Static").Cells(2, 3).Value = Feed_1_Units(1)

Feed_2 = DDERequest(Chan, "Field(9)")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(R, 4).Value = Feed_2(1)
Feed_2_Units = DDERequest(Chan, "Field(10)")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(R, 5).Value = Feed_2_Units(1)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Static").Cells(2, 4).Value = Feed_2(1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Static").Cells(2, 5).Value = Feed_2_Units(1)

Dout_1 = DDERequest(Chan, "Field(15)")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(R, 6).Value = Dout_1(1)
Dout_1_Units = DDERequest(Chan, "Field(16)")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(R, 7).Value = Dout_1_Units(1)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Static").Cells(2, 6).Value = Dout_1(1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Static").Cells(2, 7).Value = Dout_1_Units(1)

Dout_2 = DDERequest(Chan, "Field(21)")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(R, 8).Value = Dout_2(1)
Dout_2_Units = DDERequest(Chan, "Field(22)")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(R, 9).Value = Dout_2_Units(1)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Static").Cells(2, 8).Value = Dout_2(1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Static").Cells(2, 9).Value = Dout_2_Units(1)

' Close the DDE channel
DDETerminate Chan

' Insert a date/time stamp in the sheet in the same row as the data
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(R, 1).Value = Now

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Static").Cells(2, 1).Value = Now

End Sub
```

It works perfect; it takes the field (param) from WinWedge and puts it in a cell.  For the C# program, I want to connect WinWedge to my C# application and just be able to reference the field (value) so it updates the gauge in real time.

Comment: Are you asking whether translating VB.NET code to C# can be done? Anything that is possible in VB should also be possible in C# (and vice versa). There's even automatic VB to C# translators if you care to try those: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: Asad,

I have the Excel VBA code working, but when I translate to C#, it is not working.  I just don't know how to do it; that's the question.  How can I use NDde in C# to make this all work.

Comment: At least show us the relevant VBA code.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I updated the original post with the VBA code.  I would like to reference the field from WinWedge into my C# app.  Though I can't seem to connect the DDE link in C# using NDde.